# Add a single match arm to trait method without rewriting/specializing the entire function?

Tags: rust

I have a trait that uses a `match` to determine which Serde deserialization function to call (I put `Self::default` here as a placeholder). The implementation in the trait definition has match arms for formats supported by all structs that implement the trait (`"yaml"` and `"json"`). There are structs that also support `"csv"`, so I made a specialized method for those structs and rewrote the `match`.

Is there a way to not rewrite the same method to just add a single match arm? In my actual code this function does other things so it is annoying to copy-paste and add one match arm.

Here is an example:

```rust
pub trait MyTrait: Default {
    fn from_file(format: &str) -> Self {
        match format {
            "yaml" => Self::default(),
            "json" => Self::default(),
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct MyStruct {a: i32, b: i32}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn from_file(format: &str) -> Self {
        match format {
            "yaml" => Self::default(),
            "json" => Self::default(),
            "csv" => Self { a: 1, b: 1 },
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let example1 = MyStruct::from_file("yaml");
    dbg!(example1);
    
    let example2 = MyStruct::from_file("csv");
    dbg!(example2);
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b14d670f5219318e226e95b9085029ef)

Comment: Side note, why are you using string literals instead of creating an enum?

Comment: @cdhowie The string extension is parsed from a user-supplied filepath, so creating enums from parsed strings - rather than just using the strings - seems like an unnecessary extra step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make another function and use that as the fallback instead of directly panicking. Then only override that function when implementing the trait.

```rust
pub trait MyTrait: Default {
    fn from_file(format: &str) -> Self {
        match format {
            "yaml" => Self::default(),
            "json" => Self::default(),
            _ => Self::from_other_file(format),
        }
    }

    fn from_other_file(format: &str) -> Self {
        panic!("unable to deserialize from {format:?}");
    }
}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn from_other_file(format: &str) -> Self {
        match format {
            "csv" => Self { a: 1, b: 1 },
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done! Unfortunately I think the cleanest solution in my case is to keep my code as is, because I have multiple functions that match on extensions (to/from file, to/from string), and would need fallbacks for each of these, which ends up being more code than just copying the existing definition and adding another match arm.